# Go to page using paper-item in Polymer 0.5.1?

Tags: polymer, web-component, paper-elements

I created a small Polymer site (available at http://infinitech.org/beta).  I have nested an `a href` and a `core-icon` inside of a `paper-item`.  However, I have to click on the text of the `a href` in order to go to the link.  How can I make it so that clicking anywhere on the `paper-item` will go to the link (so that I don't have to click on the text of the `a href`)?  I'm using Polymer 0.5.1.  Thanks so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work for me either. I found a workaround that polymerthemes.com is using. You basically reverse the nesting of paper-item and a

```
<a href="technews.html">
    <paper-item id="technews" tabindex="0" noink>                   
        <core-icon icon="av:news" aria-label="news" role="img"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" fit="" style="pointer-events: none; display: block;"><g><path d="M20.33 4.67L18.67 3 17 4.67 15.33 3l-1.67 1.67L12 3l-1.67 1.67L8.67 3 7 4.67 5.33 3 3.67 4.67 2 3v16c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L22 3l-1.67 1.67zM12 19H4v-7h8v7zm8 0h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2H4V8h16v3z"></path></g></svg></core-icon>
        Tech News
    </paper-item>
</a>
```

This is not covered in the doco so I assume it is not the way it is intended to work. Works for me though on https://gitbacklog.appspot.com.
Although the ink seems to stop working.

Comment: The ink stopped working because of the noink attribute :).  Thanks for the help, that worked!

Comment: Haha actually meant it stopped working where I used it in my app where I don't have noink. Does the ink work for you? You're welcome btw

Comment: Works fine for me. Infinitech.org

Answer (score 0):

As per Polymer's [`paper-item` documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-item), you have to put the `<a>` tag immediately inside `<paper-item>`. Also add a `noink` attribute to prevent ripple from freezing.

```
<paper-item id="technews" tabindex="0" noink>                   
    <a href="technews.html">
        <core-icon icon="av:news" aria-label="news" role="img"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" fit="" style="pointer-events: none; display: block;"><g><path d="M20.33 4.67L18.67 3 17 4.67 15.33 3l-1.67 1.67L12 3l-1.67 1.67L8.67 3 7 4.67 5.33 3 3.67 4.67 2 3v16c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L22 3l-1.67 1.67zM12 19H4v-7h8v7zm8 0h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2h-7v-1h7v1zm0-2H4V8h16v3z"></path></g></svg></core-icon>
        Tech News
    </a>
</paper-item>
```